# IE: jQuery click doesn't trigger on div but only on p inside that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
…

    <div class="wrapper greenhouse">
    <img src="htmlData/img/background.jpg" class="background">
    <h1 class="super-title">Treibhausgasneutralität – unsere Vier-Pfad-Strategie</h1>
    <h2 class="sub-title">Zusammensetzung der Treibhausgasreduktionszertifikate (ERC) 2012</h2>

    <div class="box interact one">
        <span>1.</span>
        <p>Betriebs-<br>optimierungen</p>
    </div>
    …
```

And this is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  conditionizr();

  $('.box.interact').click(function(e){
    clicked($(e.target).attr('class').split(' ')[2]);
  });

  $('.box.interact p').click(function(e){
    clicked(target = $(e.target).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[2]);
  });

  function clicked(target){
    $('.overlay.'+target).css('display', 'block');
    $('.overlays').css('display', 'block').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
  }

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $('.overlays').stop().fadeTo('fast', 0, function(){
      $('.overlays').css('display', 'none');
      $('.overlay').css('display', 'none');
    });
  });

});
```

The click event doesn't fire on ie, but works fine in chrome etc.

Comment: Relying on the order of "class" components is a fragile practice.

Comment: The `<div>` that contains the `<p>` will get all the "click" events from the `<p>` because events "bubble" up the DOM tree.

Comment: Where is the element with `close` class? Is it dynamically added?

Comment: .close is not dynamically added. Yep, the whole construct is pretty fragile. Didn't plan enough here. Thanks for the comments.